# A question about Peter Weyl theorem

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to understand the *Peter Weyl* theorem which provides an orthonormal basis for the space $L^2(G)$ where $G$ is a compact group.

Let $\rho$ be a unitary representation of a compact group, this means that $\rho(g)^*\rho(g)=\rho(g)\rho(g)^* = I \, \, \forall g \in G$.

Denote the *matrix elements* of $\rho$ as $\phi_{e_i,e_j} = \langle \rho(g)e_i, e_j \rangle$.

The first part of the theorem relates the set of matrix elements and spaces of functions on $G$.

In particular, I'm trying to understand what does it mean that *the linear span of the set of matrix elements of unirreps of $G$ is dense in the space of continuous complex-valued functions on $G$, under uniform norm*.

So does this mean that

$$\overline{\left\{\sum_{i,j} \langle \rho(g)e_i, e_j \rangle \right\}}^{\|\cdot\|_{\infty}} = L^2(G) \, \, \, ?$$

Also in the above equation the representation $\rho$ seems to be fixed, while I may have to consider all the *unirreps* of $G$. I have been reading these things from the following [document](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05154) (page 12) and pretty confused about this.

Comment: Notice that there is the concept of "isomorphism classes of representations", and the books should mention that a representative of each class should be chosen once and for all. In Peter-Weyl theorem, this is also the case. You just need to select an irreducible representation from each class, determine the matrix elements (with a basis fixed), and the corresponding set of function generates $C(G)$ as an algebra and $L^2(G)$ as a Hilbert space.

Comment: Well, the document you enclosed is something nouveau for me... It never occurred to me that neuron networks can be concepted this way

Comment: can you be more specific in light of the math I have put in the question please?